# Post URL not working according to permalink setting

Tags: permalinks

I am having an issue where post permalink always coming with the default structure.

My permalink setting is **"http://domain.com/sample-post/"** and but the post URL coming like this "http://domain.com/?p=16721".

Impostrant thing need to notice here that Page and other custom post type URL working absolutly fine.

Only having problem with default WordPress Post.

Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: What context is the post URL coming through with ?p=#? When you click "view" and are actually viewing the post as a visitor? Or when you are in wp-admin? Have permalinks ever worked, or is this a fairly new install that you have not gotten fully working yet? Have you tried using a different browser or fully clearing your cache? Have you tried disabling all plugins to see whether one of them might be adjusting things?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using $post->guid or something like that? If so, then the GUID give you this kind of URL. Otherwise you can use get_the_permalink( $post_id )

Comment: I am first trying to view this from wordpress admin, wordpress admin also giving me same URL structure that's coming in the front end. That means the permalink structure changed everywhere.